# Python (with Django) and PHP

Tags: php, python, django

Just wondering, as I think about learning either PHP or Django (I have previous Python knowledge), what advantages do Python and Django have over PHP, what disadvantages etc.

I don't want to know which one is better, surely neither is better, both have their good sides as well as bad sides and I will probably learn both at some point. I don't want to start a flame war or anything, but please tell me some advantages and disadvantages for both to help me choose which one to learn first.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions like this have been asked many times before. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+vs+Python http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+vs+Django

Comment: I'm sorry, but none of those results actually were good answers to my question (yes, I looked at them)

Comment: Don't even try to directly compare Django to PHP.  PHP and Python are both programming languages; Django is a web application framework.  If you are doing web programming, the difference between programming with and without a framework is like night and day.  Of course, there are also PHP frameworks like CakePHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python VS PHP, Differences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464001/python-vs-php-differences)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- PHP is a popular language for web development with tons of libraries and examples online.
- Python is a modern, well-design programming language where everything is an object. It works well in many environments, including web programming, although it wasn't originally designed for that environment.

If you want a general purpose scripting language that can also be used for web development then learning Python would be a good idea. If you only plan to do web development and your main concern is to get a job, experience in PHP will make you attractive to a large number of potential employers who are already using this technology.

Comment: I will probably learn both at some point, but I guess I will go with Django as I have previous Python knowledge? I will wait for some more pointers, but thank you :)

Comment: @anto: If you have prior Python experience (and a fair bit, not just that you wrote a program once), it's def better to build on prior experience rather than throw it away...

Comment: I have some Python knowledge, but can't say much, although I have written a few small programs in it. this means I know the basic language well and a portion of the standard libraries. as of now I will probably go with Django, thanks